# VBA - PivotTable Row Count and Copy Value to New Sheet

Tags: vba, excel

**UPDATED**

I need to do a row count of the rows in the pivot table between the *"header"* row of the table and the *"grand total"* row of the table and then copy the value that the count finds, to a summary sheet.

**Header Row:**

[image: FirstRow]

**Last Row:**

[image: LastRow]

So I pretty much need to do a count from **row 4 - row 133** (which in this case is a total row count of 130) of the pivot table and paste that value in **cell B23** on the **summary sheet**.

Current Pivot Table Layout:

[image: CurrentPivotTableLayout]

I need to integrate the count into the code I already have, which is below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub FilterPivotTable()

Dim rLastCell As Range
Dim PvtTbl As PivotTable
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim LastRow1 As Long
Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("PivotTable")
Set ws2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Summary")

    LastRow1 = ws1.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    'Total - This inserts the word Total in cell B22 and pastes the total value 
'found in the grand total line of the of the pivot table, in the summary sheet 
'in line C22

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ws1.PivotTables("P1").ManualUpdate = True

    ws1.PivotTables("P1").ManualUpdate = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    With ws1.PivotTables(1).TableRange1
        Set rLastCell = .Cells(.Rows.count, .Columns.count)
        Set PvtTbl = Worksheets("PivotTable").PivotTables("P1")
        rLastCell.Copy

        With ws2

        ws2.Cells(LastRow1 + 22, 3).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        .Range("$B$22").Value = "Total"

        End With


    End With

    'Microsoft Windows - This filters the table by any vulnerabilities that have 
'the words Microsoft Windows in their description, then it inserts the words
'Microsoft Windows in cell B2 and the grand total count of this filter
'in cell C2
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ws1.PivotTables("P1").ManualUpdate = True

    ws1.PivotTables("P1").PivotFields(" Vulnerability Name").ClearAllFilters

    ws1.PivotTables("P1").PivotFields(" Vulnerability Name").PivotFilters. _
    Add Type:=xlCaptionContains, Value1:="Microsoft Windows"

    ws1.PivotTables("P1").ManualUpdate = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    With ws1.PivotTables(1).TableRange1
        Set rLastCell = .Cells(.Rows.count, .Columns.count)
        Set PvtTbl = Worksheets("PivotTable").PivotTables("P1")
        rLastCell.Copy

        With ws2

            .Cells(LastRow1 + 2, 3).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            .Range("$B$2").Value = "Microsoft Windows"

        End With

    End With

    ws1.PivotTables("P1").PivotFields(" Vulnerability Name").ClearAllFilters

    'Microsoft Office- This filters the table by any vulnerabilities that have 
'the words Microsoft Office in their description, then it inserts the words
'Microsoft Windows in cell B3 and the grand total count of this filter
'in cell C3
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ws1.PivotTables("P1").ManualUpdate = True

    ws1.PivotTables("P1").PivotFields(" Vulnerability Name").PivotFilters. _
    Add Type:=xlCaptionContains, Value1:="Microsoft Office"

    ws1.PivotTables("P1").ManualUpdate = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    With ws1.PivotTables(1).TableRange1
        Set rLastCell = .Cells(.Rows.count, .Columns.count)
        Set PvtTbl = Worksheets("PivotTable").PivotTables("P1")
        rLastCell.Copy

        With ws2

        ws2.Cells(LastRow1 + 3, 3).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        .Range("$B$3").Value = "Microsoft Office"

        End With


    End With

    ws1.PivotTables("P1").PivotFields(" Vulnerability Name").ClearAllFilters

  End Sub
```

So far I have this code to do the count:

```
lRowCount = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("P1").TableRange1.Rows.Count
```

But not sure where to integrate this and how copy the lRowCount value.

This row count needs to be done in each With block of code. So when the filter is done on vulnerability name for Microsoft Office, I need a row count done on the filtered data too.

Comment: I am confused. You are changing the pivotfield rather than filtering what is visible within a given field, no?

Comment: Damn, now I am confused too.. The intentions was that there's effectively two filters being applied - 1) Filter on the first parameter and then 2) Filter within the "filtered" results of the firs parameter. I updated the code with an example

Comment: Are these page fields? Can you show your pivottable layout? And what did your macro recorder record if you tried performing a couple óf these operations?

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of your pivot table and data - slimmed down if poss just to give an idea?

Comment: I have updated the original post significantly @SJR - I hope it makes more sense now? I unfortunately cannot post screenshots of the actual data, however I am hoping what I have provided is enough to allow you to help me.

Comment: I have updated the original post significantly @QHarr - I hope it makes more sense now? I unfortunately cannot post screenshots of the actual data, however I am hoping what I have provided is enough to allow you to help me.

Comment: Have you looked at databodyrange?

Comment: @QHarr I checked now, it seems simple enough: Worksheets("PivotTable").Activate 
ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Item(1).DataBodyRange.Select.... But how would I paste the value in the Summary Sheet?

Comment: Which value are you after?

Comment: @QHarr Actually, I am looking at it now and it wont do what I'm looking for.. I stand corrected though. While I can select the range of the table, i need to do a count of the rows. So the value I need is the count of the rows.

Comment: DataBodyRange.Rows.Count

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168491/discussion-between-qharr-and-eitel-dagnin).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simply count of the pivottable data area rows is

```
DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
```

Example:

```
Worksheets("PivotTable").ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.Rows.count
```

More verbose:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim rowCount As Long
    rowCount = Worksheets("PivotTable").ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.Rows.count
    Worksheets("Summary").Range("B23") = rowCount
End Sub
```

In your case can shorthand to:

```
PvtTbl.DataBodyRange.Rows.count
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this should get you going.

```
Sub PivotTable(ByVal ParamValue As String)
  Dim rLastCell As Range
  Dim PvtTbl As PivotTable
  Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
  Dim LastRow1 As Long
  'Your lRowCount variable
  Dim lRowCount As Long

  Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("PivotTable")
  Set ws2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Summary")
  LastRow1 = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  With ws1.PivotTables(1)
    .ManualUpdate = False
    Set rLastCell = .TableRange1.Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)
    Set PvtTbl = Worksheets("PivotTable").PivotTables("P1") '???
    '
    'Get the row count from your pivot table.
    lRowCount = .Rows.Count
    With ws2
      'Performance enhancement, as there is no need for copy/past.
      .Cells(LastRow1 + 22, 3) = rLastCell.Value
      .Range("$B$22").Value = "Total"
      '
      'Arbitrary place to copy to. Adjust to your need.
      .Cells(LastRow1 + 23, 3) = lRowCount
      .Range("$B$23").Value = "Rowcount P1"
    End With
  End With
  With ws1.PivotTables("P1")
    .ManualUpdate = True
    .PivotTables("P1").PivotFields(ParamValue).ClearAllFilters
    .PivotTables("P1").PivotFields(ParamValue).PivotFilters _
       .Add Type:=xlCaptionContains, Value1:=ParamValue
    .PivotTables("P1").ManualUpdate = False
  End With
  With ws1.PivotTables(1).TableRange1
    Set rLastCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)
    Set PvtTbl = Worksheets("PivotTable").PivotTables("P1") '???
    With ws2
      .Cells(LastRow1 + 2, 3).Value = rLastCell.Value
      .Range("$B$2").Value = "Microsoft Windows"
    End With
  End With
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
'
'Usage:
'  call PivotTable("Param1")
'  call PivotTable("Param2")
'  etc.
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply @C. van Dorsten. I copied your code and tried to test it, but the Macro wasn't showing in the list of available Macro's. However, I have edited the post to a specific question which has been answered above. Thank you again :)

Comment: Ofcourse it won't, because it takes a parameter. You should have renamed it or whatever. I just used your code to give you an example you could work with. So why the down vote?

Comment: I am not the one who down voted. Please don't assume because I didn't get the desired result with your help that I immediately down voted you.

Comment: Ok. Sorry for my remark. Had a bad day that day at work, but shouldn’t have taken it out on you. Again sorry.